# How do I change the title bar icon in Adobe AIR?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I cannot figure out how to change the title bar icon (the icon in the furthest top left corner of the application) in Adobe AIR. It is currently displaying the default 'Adobe AIR' red icon.

I have been able to change it in the system tray, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the following help?

http://groups.google.com/group/chennai-flex-user-group/browse_thread/thread/cffb9ab56450c28e

Comment: The link in this thread is now dead; the new link is http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=File_formats_1.html.

Answer (score 1):

The first link shows how to change the Taskbar Icon, the second shows the application icon I believe used on the desktop. I am going to recompile and install the application and see if it works.

Edit: Yea, the one that changes the Desktop Icon also changes the Title Bar icon. It's in the app.xml file.